# See which font file is being used by Chromium to render a block of text

Tags: html, css, linux, fonts

In Linux, not all Windows fonts are available. I can analyse a site's CSS code in Chromium to see which fonts are *preferred* to render a certain block of text, but as far as I know there's no way to determine which font file is actually being *used* to render it.

Is there a way to find out which font file is being used to render a certain block of text in Chromium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've used the Developer toolbar to get the font stack being used for the text, can you just modify the stack to see which of the fonts is actually being used?

ie. if the stack is Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; take out Arial, if the font changes, you know it was being rendered in Arial.

Comment: Interesting little trick. But I'd also like to know which font file (with its location) is being used to render the text. Is there a Linux program that lets me see which files are being read by the OS and apply a .ttf filter to the output?

Comment: I don't know of a tool that does that.... but if you know the name of the font, there's a utility called Font Manager (it's in Ubuntu Software Centre) that will give you the full path of any font installed on your system. Does that help?

Comment: I'm using KDE in openSUSE, so I don't think I can get that package. I did discover something similar that works for me. It's called fontconfig and it is installed by default with my distro. `fc-list` gives me a list of installed fonts. I can use grep to filter out relevant information.